# Telegram channel message view count

Tags: c#, .net, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using [Telegram.Bot](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot/12.0.0-beta-02) to send message to my channel using my bot which is added as an admin to the channel. I wanted to know that how can I get the post view count automatically using this package or any other package or api by polling or a call back api.
I have heard about telegram-cli but I don't know how can I use telegram-cli in windows or .net.

Answer (score 1):

Well a normal bot user **can not fetch the view count with the normal Bot API**.

But you may want to have a look at https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto and maybe even https://pwrtelegram.xyz. It is a PHP Telegram Client which can do a bit more than telegram-cli.